# Which readlineX-dev should I install?

Tags: package-management, libraries

I'm installing postgresql from source. The installation guide states:

> If you are using a package-based Linux distribution, be aware that you
>   need both the readline and readline-devel packages, if those are
>   separate in your distribution.

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and looking at synaptic I see that *both* `libreadline5` and `libreadline6` are installed, but not `libreadline5-dev` or `libreadline6-dev`.

So, should I install `libreadline5-dev` or `libreadline6-dev`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no version requirement has been specified, I suggest you to install the `libreadline-dev` package instead of `libreadlineX-dev`. (`libreadline-dev` depends on `libreadline6-dev`.) Just for your information, on 11.10 Oneiric, `libreadline5-dev` has been dropped.